# What may be meant by the $\wedge$ here?

Tags: notation, approximation, poisson-distribution

I am dealing with article
[Two Moments suffice for Poisson Approximations: The Chen-Stein Method](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176991491) by Arratia, Goldstein and Gordon.

On page 11 there is an expression with a $\wedge$ appearing in it:

> > [...] $b_3'(1~\wedge~1.4\lambda^{-1/2})$ [...]

I do not know what this $\wedge$ means here.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: I've seen this symbol used to denote the minimum of two numbers, depending on the context this might be what is meant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This symbol is used to mean "greatest lower bound", which is just the minimum of the two numbers. [This page](http://math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/structures/doku.php/lattices) was the best reference I could find.

Answer (score 3):

In probability, it is standard to use $x \wedge y$ for the minimum of $x$ and $y$ and $x \vee y$ for the maximum of $x$ and $y$.

See Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples 3e's notation page (or similar) for more common probability notation.